# SimpleDateFormat returns 24-hour date: how to get 12-hour date?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I want current time in millis and then to store it in 12 hour format but with this piece of code I am getting 24 hour format time.

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
dateforrow = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
```

can anybody suggest modifications to get the desired results?

Comment: (First place to look is the API. Also, try to summarize the issue in the title better: it makes a big first impression.)

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the last part of [the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67947328/5772882) (may also use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Change `HH` to `hh` as

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
dateforrow = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
```

Note that `dd/mm/yyyy` - will give you *minutes* instead of the *month*.

Comment: What is the last "a" for ?

Comment: @DiegoRamos It's for AM or PM

Answer (score 54):

Referring to [SimpleDataFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter | Date or Time Component | Presentation | Examples
---------------------------------------------------------
   H   |  Hour in day (0-23)    |    Number    |    0
   h   |  Hour in am/pm (1-12)  |    Number    |    12
```

Comment: private String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        return timestamp.format(new Date());
    } .    

this will give your 24 hrs fomrat..... in case of  yyyyMMddhhmmss will return 12 hr format.

Answer (score 7):

I re-encounter this in the hard way as well. H vs h, for 24-hour vs 12 hour !

Answer (score 6):

Yep, confirmed that simply using `"hh"` instead of `"HH"` fixed my issue, Since `"hh"` is for 12-Hour Format & `"HH"` is for 24-Hour Format.

Changed from this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
```

To this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
```

You can still use `"HH"` to store the time if you don't want to bother storing and dealing with the AM/PM. Then when you retrieve it, use `"hh"`.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I tested below code that worked fine :

```
    long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are ***three major problems*** with your code:

1. Using `m` [Minute in hour] at the place of `M` [Month in year].
2. Using `H` [Hour in day (0-23)] instead of `h` [Hour in am/pm (1-12)]. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about these two points.
3. Not using `Locale` with `SimpleDateFormat`. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

So, the instantiation with the correct format would be:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

## *java.time*

Note that the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>, released in March 2014 as part of Java SE 8 standard library.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(odt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Uxbz7V)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
  Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();

  SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
  String str=sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

use `hh` in place of `HH`

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the code

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String strDate,StringsourceFormate,
                                     String destinyFormate) {
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormate);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(strDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    df = new SimpleDateFormat(destinyFormate);
    return df.format(date);

}
```

and pass the value into the function like that,

```
getFormatedDate("21:30:00", "HH:mm", "hh:mm aa");
```

or checkout this documentation [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) for StringsourceFormate and destinyFormate.

Answer (score -1):

See code example below:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
out.println(formattedDate);
```