# How to convert date and time stored in string to 24 format time in android?

Tags: java, android

I have my date and time stored in string i.e my string contains str ="18/01/2013 5:00:00 pm". How can I convert it to 24 format time in android?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two SimpleDateFormat instances: one to parse the input as a date and a second to format the date as a string with the desired format.

For example, `formattedDate` in the code below will be `18/01/2013 17:00:00`:

```
String str = "18/01/2013 5:00:00 pm";
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date dt = input.parse(str);

SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = output.format(dt); //contains 18/01/2013 17:00:00
```

Notes:

- `hh` is for Hour in am/pm (1-12) whereas `HH` is for Hour in day (0-23).
- for more formatting options, check the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    String str ="18/01/2013 5:00:00 pm";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").parse(str);
    str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
    System.out.println(str);
```

output

```
18/01/2013 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

To get AM PM and 12 hour date format use `hh:mm:ss a` as string formatter WHERE `hh`  is for 12 hour format and `a` is for AM PM format.

*Note:* HH is for `24` hour and hh is for `12` hour date format

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```

**Example**

```
String date = "18/01/2013 5:00:00 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for that:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14053087/1777090) which was opposite to your requirement. Just posted the link so you might get the idea of difference that HH and hh makes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the java SimpleDateFormat class.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
df.parse(date);
```

The upper case HH use a 24h format