# SimpleDateFormat android not formatting as expected

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm trying to use SimpleDateFormat for formatting a date represented by 3 ints. 
It looks like this:

```
...
SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
SimpleDateFormat sdfMinute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdfSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

String string_hours = sdfHour.format(hours);
String string_minutes = sdfMinute.format(minutes);
String string_seconds = sdfSecond.format(seconds);
```

and the output of

```
Log.d("tag", "Time string is: " + string_hours + ":" + string_minutes + ":" + string_seconds);
```

is always

```
Time string is: 19:00:00
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your expected one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat.format expects a Date, not an int. The method you're using, which is the overloaded version that accepts a long, is actually expecting milliseconds from the epoch, not an hour a minute or a second as you're doing.

The right way of using it should be :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String timeString = sdfHour.format(new Date());
```

Using "new Date()" as in this example, will give you the current time. If you need to format some other time (like one hour ago, or something from a database etc..) pass to "format" the right Date instance.

If you need the separated, for some reason, then you can still use it, but this other way :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
SimpleDateFormat sdfMinute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdfSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");

Date now = new Date();

String string_hours = sdfHour.format(now);
String string_minutes = sdfMinute.format(now);
String string_seconds = sdfSecond.format(now);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
SimpleDateFormat sdfMinute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdfSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
```

Use this:

```
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateformatted = dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime());
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14053079/1777090)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String CurrentTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling wrong `format` method. You should supply a `Date` argument to a proper one, instead you are using this [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29), inherited from `Format` class:

```
public final String format(Object obj)
```

Why does it work? Because of auto-boxing procedure in Java. You provide an `int`, it's automatically boxed to `Integer` which is a successor of `Object`