# How to change time format from 24h to 12h

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I am using TextView to set date and time with day name, but time is showing in 24hours and I want to set it in 12hours format. can any one help me what should I change in this format.

```
textDateTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 5):

It's about the format you put in `SimpleDateFormat`, as you are using `HH` (24-hour). Try `hh` (12-hour format).
See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053079/simpledateformat-returns-24-hour-date-how-to-get-12-hour-date) or [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

Rather than hard-code a format, automatically localize.

```java
LocalTime
.now()
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/q0K7Jj).

> 5:08 PM

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use the terrible `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

You appear to want the current time as seen in a particular time zone. Time zone is crucial. For any given moment, the time-of-day (and the date) vary around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" )
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

Let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = now.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).